# Как выпилить w3support.net из выдачи google

Tags: google-search

Дико бесит, что при поиске какой-то нужной инфы, половина выдачи гугла ведет на этот сайт, который, по сути, является переведенным на русский с помощью google translate, stackoverflow.com. Может есть какой-то способ в настройках google убрать его из выдачи. В идеале user-script или плагин который при заходе на w3support перекидывал бы на оригинальную тему на стеке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, у google недавно появились такие [возможности](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/hide-sites-to-find-more-of-what-you.html). Можно прямо зайти на страницу [настроек](http://www.google.com/reviews/t) и внести туда нужный сайт. Это уже работает на google.com, но вроде еще не работает на google.ru.

Answer (score 4):

Еще можно добавить в строку поиска фразу

```
-site:w3support.net
```

Или можно авторизоваться и воcпользоваться прямой ссылкой - http://www.google.com/reviews/t?hl=en
Выпилить можно до 500 сайтов.

Comment: знаю про это, но это костыль. Хочется вбить один раз 2-3 спам-сайта и забыть про них на всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Для Хрома нашел плагин [Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef). Это именно то что нужно, думаю и для других браузеров нечто подобное есть.

Comment: Минусую за злостное использование слова *плагин* для обозначения *расширения*.